# Send Emai to the user based on some condition

Tags: java, email

I have a requirement to send mail to an User if the applications and servers are down/up. So I have coded in such a way that if application or server is down a mail should be sent,else when all applications are up a different  mail should be sent. I am iterating because I have n number of apps and servers.

**i**
*The following code must be executed only if both apps and servers are down*

```
for(i=0;i<resp.size();i++){
                    for(j=0;j<obj.size();j++){

                if((obj.get(j).get("status").equals("DOWN"))&&(resp.get(i).get("status").equals("DOWN"))){
                    sender.sendMail(
                            "Demo Apps & Server Status","Hi,"
                            + "<br><br>"+
                            "<u>The Following Servers are DOWN : </u>"
                                    + '\n'
                                    + "<table cellpadding='10' cellspacing='10'><th>Name</th><th>Status</th><tr><td>"
                                    + obj.get(j).get("name") + "</td>"
                                    + "<td>" + obj.get(j).get("status")
                                    + "</td></tr></table>" + '\n'+"<u>The Following Applications are DOWN : </u>"
                                    + '\n'
                                    + "<table cellpadding='15',cellpadding='15'><th>Name</th>"
                                    + "<th>Status</th>"
                                    + '\n'
                                    + "<tr align='left'><td align='left'>"
                                    + resp.get(i).get("name")
                                    + "</td>"
                                    + "<td align='right'>"
                                    + resp.get(i).get("status")
                                    + "</td>"
                                    + "</tr></table>"+ "<br><br>" + "Thanks & Regards," + "<br>"
                                    + "<b>Smart Miles Support Team</b>",Constants.setFrom, Constants.emailTO);
                    System.out.println("The servers & app down Email was Sent Succesfully...");
                }
                    }   

                }
```

**ii**
*The following code must be executed only if servers are down*

```
for(i=0;i<resp.size();i++){
                    if ((resp.get(i).get("status").equals("DOWN"))) {

                        sender.sendMail(
                                "Demo Apps & Server Status","Hi,"
                                + "<br><br>"+
                                "<u>The Following Applications are</u>"
                                        + '\n'
                                        + "<table cellpadding='15',cellpadding='15'><th>Name</th>"
                                        + "<th>Status</th>"
                                        + '\n'
                                        + "<tr align='left'><td align='left'>"
                                        + resp.get(i).get("name")
                                        + "</td>"
                                        + "<td align='right'>"
                                        + resp.get(i).get("status")
                                        + "</td>"
                                        + "</tr></table>"
                                        + '\n'
                                        + "<u>The Following Servers are up and running</u>"
                                        + '\n'
                                        + "<ul><li>Demo Apps</li><li>L&T Infotech Appstore</li><li>L&T Appstore</li><li>DCP Onetouch</li><li>Viacom</li></ul>"+ "<br><br>" + "Thanks & Regards," + "<br>"
                                        + "<b>Smart Miles Support Team</b>",
                                Constants.setFrom, Constants.emailTO);
                        System.out.println("The Apps down Email was Sent Succesfully...");

                        }
                    }
            }
```

**iii**
*The following code must be executed only if apps are down*

```
for(j=0;j<obj.size();j++){

                 if ((obj.get(j).get("status").equals("DOWN"))) {


                        sender.sendMail(
                                "Demo Apps & Server Status","Hi,"
                                + "<br><br>"+
                                "<u>The Following Servers are DOWN : </u>"
                                        + '\n'
                                        + "<table cellpadding='10' cellspacing='10'><th>Name</th><th>Status</th><tr><td>"
                                        + obj.get(j).get("name") + "</td>"
                                        + "<td>" + obj.get(j).get("status")
                                        + "</td></tr></table>" + '\n'
                                        + "<b>All the Applications are UP and RUNNING.</b>"+ "<br><br>" + "Thanks & Regards," + "<br>"
                                        + "<b>Smart Miles Support Team</b>",

                                Constants.setFrom, Constants.emailTO);
                        System.out.println("The servers down Email was Sent Succesfully...");
```

1. In my code, if apps are down both **i** & **iii** is getting
   executed.Only **iii** must be executed.
2. if servers are down both
       **i** & **ii** is getting executed. Only **ii** must be executed.
3. If both are down only  **i** must get executed, but all three are
       executed.
4. I am getting n number of mails if n number of
       apps/server is down. I must get only one mail with the n number of
       apps and servers.

Comment: You are using `==` operator to compare String values, use `equals()` instead. Check the link to the duplicate discussion.

Comment: Even if I use .equals, only the else part is getting executed

Comment: The logic of this program snippet looks very suspicious. What's the point of testing a list element's field using index i or j before the loop is entered? @Eran the comparison is just a red herring - the entire code is broken, I think. Reopening and editing the == to equals  might be beneficial.

Comment: @Vaishnavi Explain the logic of the loops and ifs. **Always use for statements with declaring the loop counter in the for statement, e.g. `for( int i = 0;...)` (unless you are very, very sure what you are doing).**

Comment: @Vaishnavi Can you explain what is exact problem??

Comment: please find my edited question